# Hashcode of an int

Tags: java, int, hashcode, primitive

What is the hashcode of a primitive type, such as int?

for example, let's say num was an interger.

```
int hasCode = 0;

if (num != 0) {
  hasCode = hasCode + num.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: You can't call methods on primitives. Although it can be autoboxed, and then as an `Integer` (or similar) you'll get `Integer.hashCode`.

Comment: In that case, we could be more helpful and add what the hashCodes would be for the wrapper classes.

Comment: The hashcode of an integer is the integer itself.

Comment: @DennisMeng Can you not read the API docs?

Comment: I could, but the point of my comment was that we shouldn't shut the OP down just because of a minor technicality. The point of my comment was that we should probably be giving answers closer to the actual spirit of the problem.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For the `hashCode` of an `int` the most natural choice is to use the `int` itself. A better question is what to use for the `hashCode` of a `long` since it doesn't fit into the `int`-sized hashcode. Generally, your best source for that—and all `hashCode`-related questions—would be [Effective Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html).

Here's what Effective Java recommends (and the JDK uses) for the `long` type:

```
(int) (value ^ (value >>> 32))
```

Comment: I got curious about the `long` hash code and have looked it up, it's: `(int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));`

Comment: @platzhirsch Yes, that's how it's implemented in `java.lang.Long`, and that's what Effective Java recommends.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik actually I think [this](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) is probably a lot more useful.

Comment: @veer You mean browsing through the JDK code? There will be no mention of a primitive type's hashcode there. Maybe you mean inspecting `hashCode` of primitive wrappers---in that case I'd recommend [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Long.java#Long.hashCode%28%29) over the unwieldy download.

Answer (score 48):

Taken from the `Integer.class` source code:

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code for this {@code Integer}.
 *
 * @return  a hash code value for this object, equal to the
 *          primitive {@code int} value represented by this
 *          {@code Integer} object.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    return value;
}
```

Where `value` is the value of the integer.

Comment: Note: It's correct but the question was meant for primitive int and not Integer object holding 'integer' value

Answer (score 9):

No `hashCode()` method for primitive type `int` available.

`Integer` is Wrapper class type and `hashcode()` returns an `int`

Answer (score 1):

The `java.lang.Integer.hashCode()` method returns a hash code value for primitive value of `int` but represented as an `Integer` object.

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code value for an Integer,
 * equal to the primitive int value it represents.
 */
public class IntegerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer i = new Integer("20");
        System.out.println("Value = " + i.hashCode());
    }

}`
```

**Results:**

> Value = 20

Source Link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_hashcode.htm

Comment: the retval intermediary variable isn't really necessary in this code as it is only being used once.