# Why std::hash<int> seems to be identity function

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, identity, stdhash

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::hash<int> hash_f;
    std::cout << hash_f(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << hash_f(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << hash_f(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << hash_f(3) << std::endl;
}
```

I compile with "g++ main.cpp -std=c++11" and then the result is :

```
0
1
2
3
```

Why is this happening? I don't use any library and I don't have a specialized hashing function.

Addendum : I wanted to define the hash for an unordered_set of unordered_set of int with the hash of a set being the sum of its components hashs, but if it's just identity it's not cool because the hash of {2,4} is the same than the hash of {1,5}. The simplest way to avoid that is may be to use the std::hash double function.

Comment: Why do you expect it to not be the identity function?

Comment: _f(x) = x_ is perfectly unique for every input. :)

Comment: Identity is the obvious choice for a simple hash over integers.  (Obviously, it would be a poor choice for a cryptographic hash - that needs to be a one-way function).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11890805/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3893782/

Comment: I don't really understand your addendum. Either way please do not change the question after-the-fact.

Comment: @dyp: Those are not even the same languages!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit These are *intentionally* not the same languages. Other languages have to solve a similar problem, albeit with different trade-offs.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/hash_append

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers cover the rationale behind the identity function very well. To address your addendum:

> I wanted to define the hash of an unordered_set as the sum of its components hashs, but if it's just identity it's not cool because the hash of {2,4} is the same than the hash of {1,5}. The simplest way to avoid that is may be to use the std::hash function.

As you can see, using the `+` operator to combine hashes is not the best idea.  To be more robust, you could use the XOR (`^`) operator, or take inspiration from the approach taken, e.g., by `boost::hash_combine` ([details in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780/magic-number-in-boosthash-combine)):

```
seed ^= hash_value(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
```

As an example, for your two integer pairs (1,5 / 2,4), and a `seed` of 0, this would work out to

```
uint32_t seed = 0;
seed ^= 1 + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
seed ^= 5 + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
// 3449077526

uint32_t seed = 0;
seed ^= 2 + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
seed ^= 4 + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2);
// 3449077584
```

Comment: why you can't just use : seed ^= x ? why do you need + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed << 6) + (seed >> 2) ?

Comment: You can just go for a simple XOR (as I wrote); but have a look at the [SO article I linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780/magic-number-in-boosthash-combine) for some rationale behind the Boost approach.

Comment: A simple practical example: combining the hashes of two 0s would in this case be `0 ^ 0`, which is again 0. But you could argue that two 0s should produce a different hash from a single 0. Another rationale is that two consecutive hash values should be far apart from each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry, I can't select 2 answers, I should have ask an other question for the addendum and select your answer.

Comment: No worries, it's fine as it is.

Answer (score 13):

It seems its identity, its allowed as its distinct..
From [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

> The actual hash functions are implementation-dependent and are not required to fulfill any other quality criteria except those specified above. Notably, some implementations use trivial (identity) hash functions which map an integer to itself. In other words, these hash functions are designed to work with unordered associative containers, but not as cryptographic hashes, for example. ....

Answer (score 9):

It seems completely reasonable for the hash function `int`→`int` to be identity, and it's not clear why you are surprised by that. Performing any further computation would be pointless. This is, in fact, a *perfect hash* in every sense of the term.

Remember, `std::hash` is supposed to (almost uniquely) *identify* values, not encrypt them.

It's only when you want to hash types larger than that of the hash itself (say, `uint9999999_t`) that you need to do some work to "compress" the value into the size of the hash.

Comment: For an input which is bounded by values greater than int min and smaller than int max, e.g. (-1000, +1000), the distribution will be ... not optimal.

Comment: @dyp: If you have such an input then why are you storing it in an `int`? You're always free to provide your own range-aware hash function customised for your application, but I see no reason for the default implementation to make _any_ assumptions in that regard.

Comment: Add a single entry of `INT_MAX` and you have the same issue, except that you have to use `int`. To me, it is debatable whether or not the default implementation should try to compensate common skews in the input data; therefore to me the question is, *what are the arguments why not to try to do that?*

Comment: @dyp: I don't think you can come up with any "common skews". You're chasing optimisations without any data! If the default implementation optimises for case _X_ then it's suddenly suboptimal for case _Y_. Let the default do the sensible, obvious thing then replace it with your own specific hash function if you need one.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it again, the modulo applied after the hash will distribute things too, so the impact is not as high as I originally thought. Distributions that collide with a trivial hash functions look much more weird, e.g. (N, N+10) where N is the applied modulo. -- Yes, I don't have any data for "common skews", nor do I know if there are few enough of them to optimize for. But it's not me who decides on a default; a default should be there if it works well enough for many cases and then you need those cases to test. Otherwise, no default should be provided IMHO.

Comment: according to cppreference.com, the hash function object seems to be `int-->size_t`, not `int-->int`.

Comment: *"Performing any further computation would be pointless. This is, in fact, a perfect hash in every sense of the term."* - this completely misses the trade-offs here, namely between identity hashes *post modulo table size* (which is what matters) being extremely collision prone in the worst case (even with a prime number of buckets), vs saving CPU time on stronger hashing, folding near-incrementing values across buckets more uniformly than stronger hashing does, and (very minor benefit) having better cache locality if lookups happen to be done in order of increasing key.