# LINQ Distinct Not Working

Tags: vb.net, linq, distinct, iequalitycomparer, iequatable

I'm trying to select distinct instances from my class but it's not working, even after implements IEqualityComparer (as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) AND IEquatable

Could someone help?

```
Public Class Teste
  Implements IEquatable(Of Teste), IEqualityComparer(Of Teste)
  Private _Codigo As Integer
  Public Property Codigo() As Integer
    Get
      Return _Codigo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
      _Codigo = value
    End Set
  End Property
  Public Sub New(id As Integer)
    Me.Codigo = id
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
    Return DirectCast(obj, Teste).Codigo = Me.Codigo
  End Function

  Public Function Equals1(other As Teste) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of Teste).Equals
    Return Me.Codigo = other.Codigo
  End Function

  Public Function Equals2(x As Teste, y As Teste) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Teste).Equals
    Return x.Codigo = y.Codigo
  End Function

  Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As Teste) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Teste).GetHashCode
    Return DirectCast(obj, Teste).Codigo
  End Function
End Class
```

Testing:

```
Dim p1 As New Teste(78)
Dim p2 As New Teste(78)
Dim l As New List(Of Teste) From {p1, p2}
MsgBox(l.Count())
MsgBox(l.Distinct().Count())
```

I've got two msgbox both showing "2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the `Distinct` method what equality comparer to use. I would also split that out into it's own class. For example:

```
Public Class TesteEqualityComparer 
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Teste)

    Public Function Equals2(x As Teste, y As Teste) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Teste).Equals
        Return x.Codigo = y.Codigo
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode1(obj As Teste) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Teste).GetHashCode
        Return obj.Codigo.GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

And now your query is:

```
MsgBox(l.Distinct(New TesteEqualityComparer()).Count())
```

Comment: For the hashcode, the DirectCast isn't needed (left over from the OP's code I guess).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Indeed, but I've not done VB.Net for 7/8 years so didn't touch it!

Comment: @AndrewMorton Edited that out, and improved it a bit more, using the `Codigo` property as the hashcode is naughty.

Comment: I was under the impression that an integer is perfectly good to use as its own hashcode, e.g. [Hashcode of an int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11890843/1115360), because the hashcode itself is a integer and there is zero chance of a collision.